# Не хочет отсчитывать интервал в Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html

У меня проблема, в том, что в браузере Mozilla не хочет отсчитывать таймер, хотя в других браузерах все работает.

Помогите разобраться, может что не так делаю?

```
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (!document.getElementById("video").paused) {
        if (document.getElementById("timer_span").innerHTML == "0") {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("timer_span").innerHTML--;
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: А что означают два дефиса в else?

Comment: @Дмытрык https://learn.javascript.ru/operators#%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82

Comment: А, это инкремент). А что инкремент в данном случае применим? InnerHTML, вроде бы строку возвращает

Comment: @Дмытрык строка автоматически приводится к числу

Comment: А вот по ссылочки, указано, что декремент можно применить только к переменной. В данном случае,  это правило соблюдено?... не судите строго, я только учусь

Comment: @Дмытрык да, `document.getElementById("timer_span").innerHTML` это вполне переменная

Comment: А условие `(!document.getElementById("video").paused)` в FF выполняется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следующий код корректно тикает в браузерах под Win10:

- Mozilla Firefox 57.0
- Google Chrome 62.0.3202.94
- Microsoft Edge 40.15063.674.0
- Microsoft IE 11.726.15063.0

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="timer_span">5</span>
    <script>
      var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (document.getElementById("timer_span").innerHTML == "0") {
          clearInterval(timer);
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById("timer_span").innerHTML--;
        }
      }, 1000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Что конкретно и где (на какой версии) не работает?

Comment: Проблема была исправлена! Эта часть кода, тупо не доходила, до работы. Этот код - часть одного эвента "StartAd", по итогу, event крашился до этого кода.

Comment: Тогда странно, что мой ответ, первым это подтвердивший, не был вами принят.

Answer (score 1):

Код, представленный вами, корректен:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  if (!document.getElementById("video").paused) {
    if (document.getElementById("timer_span").innerHTML == "0") {
      clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
      document.getElementById("timer_span").innerHTML--;
    }
  }
}, 1000);
```

Рекомендую обратить внимание на условия, записанные внутри функции, а именно:

```
if (!document.getElementById("video").paused)
```

попробуйте убрать это условие, либо добавьте небольшой кусочек кода подобный этому:

```
console.log(!document.getElementById("video").paused);
```

перед вашим условием, чтобы увидеть в консоли и понять, почему таймер не отсчитывает. Без этой проверки, в браузере *Mozilla Firefox 57.0* все работает исправно. Попробуйте следующий код и посмотрите, что у вас в консоли, после запуска:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  console.log(!document.getElementById("video").paused);
  if (!document.getElementById("video").paused) {
    if (document.getElementById("timer_span").innerHTML == "0") {
      clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
      document.getElementById("timer_span").innerHTML--;
    }
  }
}, 1000);
```

Скорее всего там будет `false` - что вполне логично, почему таймер не отсчитывает, ведь код внутри блока условия не выполняется.